# What is more robust and reliable of writing an if statement that uses process substitution?

Tags: bash

I have come across a "situation" on `bash`, which I don't know the right answer to (I researched, but found no convincing answer to this).

Basically, the problem is related to a specific `bash` process substitution being saved first into a variable versus being expanded directly on an `if` statement. **My goal is reliability/robustness above other things**.

Consider that you have the choice of the two following code snippets, and you can only pick one of the two, without changing them:

Code 1:

```
var2="$(cut -d',' -f5 <<< "$var1")"
if [ "$var3" = "$var2" ]; then ...
```

Code 2:

```
if [ "$var3" = "$(cut -d',' -f5 <<< "$var1")" ]; then ...
```

**Considering that the goal is robustness/reliability, which one of the above (`Code 1` or `Code 2`) would you use, and why?** Feel free to expand your answer to include other areas you feel appropriate as well after discussing the reliability issue.

Comment: @JamilSaid Asking about the `bash` version is reasonable. Asking about Python and/or Java as well makes the question too broad.

Comment: @chepner fair enough, I removed the bonus question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JamilSaid, I think your question is reasonable, though it falls a little outside of the typical SO questions.  @chepner's answer talks about how to write your specific code in a better and optimal way (which is very nice), rather than the principle.

I would pick the first approach for the following reasons:

- It's more readable - longer `if` conditions are usually harder to read
- In case we have error handling, it is easier to insert that code right after the process substitution step
- Better delegation of responsibilities - the `if` condition's job is just to check the strings and not worry about how they came into
  existence

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not interested in optimizing the `cut` code (although it is totally fine for someone to suggest this after choosing one of the options). That code is not mine, by the way. I was presented with this question and could not answer it in a satisfactory way, which made me think a lot about it.

Comment: I was also leaning towards `code 1`. Better delegation of responsibilities is a reasonable point. But what I grip with is that `code 1` has an extra step to achieve (basically) the same thing as `code 2` does. That makes me a little wary of choosing `code 1`. I am still not sure that one would be superior to the other.

Comment: Readability wins over brevity in this case.

Comment: I've dug a little more on this and "Better delegation of responsibilities" (i.e. better "Separation of concerns" SoC) convinced me that the first approach is better. Even if the first approach has more steps, the SoC is so important for creating code that is more modular, that I think using the other form would not be recommendable.

Comment: "Separation of concerns" is a much more appropriate term here.  Thanks @JamilSaid.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one is desirable; use `read` to split the string instead of `cut`.

```
IFS=, read -r _ _ _ _ var2 _ <<< "$var1"
if [ "$var3" = "$var2" ]; then
```

You might use an array instead:

```
IFS=, read -a fields <<< "$var1"
if [ "$var3" = "${fields[4]}" ]; then
```

If for some reason you *have* to use `cut`, it really doesn't matter *at all* which one you choose.

Comment: The question specifically stated that the code snippets should not be changed. Also, it specifically asked for `which one would you pick` if you HAD to make a choice.

Comment: It's a ridiculous artificial constraint.

Comment: @JamilSaid Just because the answer was it doesn't matter, doesn't mean he didn't answer. And this is more *reliable* **and** *robust* then either of OP's choices.

Comment: @chepner no, you are missing the point. Consider that you COULD NOT change the snippets. It happens frequently that you have to deal with less than optimal code written by others that you can't change. I left the door open to comment and expand on the answer after you choose one of the snippets (which cannot be changed).

Comment: This site is not for inane hypotheticals; it is for *practical* questions. If you cannot change the code, what is the point of worrying about an alternative that you can't implement?

Comment: @chepner it is a practical question. It is between the choice of two code constructions, which one would you use and why.

Comment: @chepner Could you expand a little on why `cut` is worse? I'm curious

Comment: Because you're starting an external program to do something that the shell can do itself.